# sql query group by statement suggestion

Tags: sql, database

I am learning database query and want to find out the following SQL query from the HR Schema in Oracle database.

Find number of employees in each salary group. Salary groups are considered as follows.

Group 1: 0k to <5K, 5k to <10k, 10k to <15k, and so on.

what will be the possible query code ??

Tables are as follows: There are seven tables in total

REGIONS: REGION_ID, REGION_NAME

COUNTRIES: COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME, REGION_ID

LOCATIONS: LOCATION_ID, STREET_ADDRESS, POSTAL_CODE, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, COUNTRY_ID

DEPARTMENTS: DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, MANAGER_ID, LOCATION_ID

EMPLOYEES: EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID

JOB_HISTORY: EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID

JOBS: JOB_ID, JOB_TITLE, MIN_SALARY, MAX_SALARY

Comment: Please show what you've attempted (even if it's wrong), sample data, and an expected outcome.  With just a list of tables and column names (without even the data types...) no one can really help you much.  I will say that your solution will likely involve a `CASE` statement to create a grouping, a `COUNT()` and a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

I first use a common table expression (CTE) to calculate the different groups using a case statement...

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Emp_ID, 
            case when salary >= 0 salary < 5000 then "<5K"
            when salary >= 5000 and salary < 10000 then "<10k"
            when salary >= 10000 and salary < 15000 then "<15k"
            else "UDF" end as SalaryGroup
FROM Employees)

SELECT count(Emp_ID) as Cnt, SalaryGroup
FROM CTE
GROUP BY SalaryGroup;
```

I then select from that table to give you the counts by the salary group calculated.

Answer (score -1):

```
select trunc(salary/5000,00) e,
       count(*) 
from EMPLOYEES 
group by trunc(SALARY/5000,0) 
ORDER by e asc
```